# use of property decorator in Django to calculate Sum

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, decorator

I have two moldes in which one model consists of file field. I have to calculate total size of the files in the parent model within the property decorator. I think this could also be done inside the serializer class using the serializer method but I want within the property decorator.

```
class Package(models.Model):   

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    />....................other fields.........../

    **/.........problem is here..../**
    @property
    def folder_size(self):
        all = self.details.all()
        
        all.annotate()
        return total
```

Here I need help to calculate the sum of all files sizes of a single package.

```
Class Details(models.Model):
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,
                               related_name='details')
    notes = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def file_size(self):
        return self.file.size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use properties in a [**`.annotate(…)`** clause [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) or any other queryset expression: these are done at the *database* side and the database does not know anything about properties, models, or Python.

Furthermore we can not transform this expression into something the queryset can understand, since a `FileField` only stores the path of the file, not its size.

You thus will need to manually determine the size, for example with:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    # …
    
    @property
    def folder_size(self):
        return sum(detail.file_size for detail in self.details.only('file'))
```

here the [**`.only(…)`** clause [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) can limit the bandwidth by only fetching the `file` column, but still the processing has to be done at the Python/Django level.

Comment: Thanks as always @Willem , so I think its better to calculate the sum inside view, annotate it and put the field inside the serializer class..

Comment: @Reactoo: you can not use annotate: the database does not store the file size, only the file name, so the database has no means to determine the size of the files.

Comment: The thing is I have already determined the file size of a single file in the child class above using the property decorator... Now i only need to sum it all..

Comment: @Reactoo: yes indeed. It thus makes it more convenient to determine the size of the folder, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Willem, i have put the green tick on your answer, but i will try to calculate it in a view.

Comment: Hello @Willem I tried `qs =Package.objects.annotate(ftotal_size=Sum('details__file_size'))` but I got the error saying `FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'file_size' for BigAutoField or join on the field not permitted.` can you help?

Comment: @Reactoo: but you can *not* use a property as annotation. So you can not use `file_size` in `.annotate(..)`, `.aggregate(..)`, `.filter(..)`, etc.

Comment: No no, I used it inside a view ... as i said i am not using property now.

Comment: @Reactoo: well the `file_size` in `.annotate(ftotal_size=Sum('details__file_size'))` makes no sense, regardless whether that is in a view, property, serializer, etc. Simply because the database does not know anything about the Python classes, and the database even can not access files nor inspect the file size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242204/discussion-between-reactoo-and-willem-van-onsem).